# SimilarMobileTech: Find alternative libraries across different mobile platforms

Tags: app, website

### Screenshot

[image]

### About

Mobile development is more and more popular and it is very likely that developers want to switch from one platform to another e.g., from IOS to Android. They always asks questions about counterpart libraries to the one that he is familiar with in the old language, e.g.,

- [Does anyone know if in Android there is similar library to Assets Library Framework in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877709/does-anyone-know-if-in-android-there-is-similar-library-to-assets-library-framew)
- [alternative of leanback library for KitKat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35956912/alternative-of-leanback-library-for-kitkat)
- [Skewed ListView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37641281/skewed-listview-in-android)

Although it is not allowed to propose such questions in Stack Overflow (off-topic), there are still many similar questions and they are always with high scores.

Motivated by such questions, we propose an approach to automatically answer these analogy questions by applying [Word2Vec](https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/) algorithm with incorporating the [knowledge graph](https://graphofknowledge.appspot.com/) to the tags in Stack Overflow.

Thus, given a library(tag), the [website](https://graphofknowledge.appspot.com/similartech/mobile.html) can render:

- No more than 4 libraries in three different mobile platforms (maybe less), ios, android, windows-phone;
- The tagwiki and their asking trend of these recommended libraries in Stack Overflow;

### Website

Our website can be visited in https://graphofknowledge.appspot.com/similartech/mobile.html

### Contact

For any questions, bugs, suggestions, please leave a message in this post or contact me in my email wchccy@gmail.com.